# Возможны ли инъекции в сессию?

Tags: mysql, sql-injection

Возможна ли SQL инъекция при таком раскладе?

```
$user_id = $_SESSION["user_id"];
$db->Query("SELECT * FROM db_users_a, db_users_b WHERE db_users_a.id = db_users_b.id AND db_users_a.id = '$user_id'");
```

Comment: Данные в сессию записываются исключительно на стороне севера, если при записи в переменную вы пропустите sql то тогда да, но если данные достоверны то нет

Comment: @naym, не совсем понял. Что в моём случае нужно, чтобы появилась инъекция?

Comment: Ну в конце концов если вы сомневаетесь, то обработайте real_escape_string($_SESSION["user_id"])

Comment: А зачем $user_id в кавычках? Если $user_id - integer, то его можно просто скастовать в int.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[[@ModaL](/users/6646/modal)](/users/6646/modal) sql возможна примерно при таком сценарии.
Получили вы от пользователя какие то данные, и забыв их проверить на sql xss и прочее записали их в $_SESSION["someData"]. Вот в этом случае - в  $_SESSION["someData"] может быть что угодно. Если же Вы перед записью проверили данные, вырезали из них все подозрительное и опасное, то тогда все будет ок.

Answer (score 0):

Sql injection может бфть всегда. Даже с числом.

http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2014/08/08/the-bobbytables-culture/